# Supporting gzip response from Google Geocoding API

Tags: gzip, google-geocoding-api

I am using the Google Geocoding API v3[1] from an iOS application but can't get it to return a gzip response. The v2 was much more lightweight but with v3 I'm getting a ~20kb JSON response .. which might take some time to retrieve on a bad GPRS connection, so I would really like to get a gzipped result back.

Am I wondering if I'm doing anything wrong in my call or if their API really doesn't support gzip or deflate. It just sounds strange to me.

This is a what I'm doing in my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=55,12&sensor=true"];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[req setValue:@"gzip,deflate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

NSURLConnection *c = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
  initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

I've tried with only "gzip" and "deflate" too. Same result.

[1] http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why, but it seems to have something to do with the `User-Agent` header. When I request the API page with Firefox (`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2`) I get a gzipped response. When I request the page with cURL (specifically asking for a compressed response), I get a plain response. However, if I override cURL's default agent to the Mozilla one, I *do* get a compressed response.

Comment: You're spot on! I used the Firefox header and I'm now getting gzipped results back. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At least for the GData APIs, you need to add a `User-Agent` header that contains the string `gzip`, see https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#gzip.  Hoping this would work with the [Directions API service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/), I tried it and was able to get a gzip response.